# Python - how to reset class member based on its name

Tags: python-2.7

I have a class with two members - m1 is a string and m2 is a dictionary.

I want to reset m2 by calling myA.m2.reset() equivalently to self.m2.clear(); and reset m1 by calling myA.m1.reset() equivalently to self.m1 = None.

So how can I implement this reset method in class A?

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.m1 = None
        self.m2 = {}

    def reset(self):
        """
         if it is m2: self.m2.clear()
         elif it is m1: self.m1 = None
        """

myA = A()
myA.m2[1] = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: OP I'm very sorry - my suggestion to use descriptors seemed like a good idea, but it isn't going to be enable you to write code like `myA.m2.reset()` in a robust way.

I'll keep this answer here for reference in case it gives you any ideas.

---

This is a job for python [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors)!

If I understand, you want to be able to do something like this:

```
myA.some_member.reset()
```

...and have custom behavior depending on what "type" (I use that word loosely) of member it is. You could get this working just fine for the dict-like `m2` member:

```
class ResettableDict(dict):
    def reset(self):
        self.clear()

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
    self.m2 = ResettableDict()
```

The problem you are going to run into, though, is that you cannot do something similar by subclassing `str`, since strings are immutable (i.e., they can't be "cleared" like a `dict`). Furthermore, when you use the assignment operator to give your `ResettableString` member some value, it will cease to be a `ResettableString`. Example:

```
class ResettableString(str):
    pass # Just a placeholder for this example
```

Test:

```
>>> myA = A()
>>> myA.m2[1] = 2 
>>> type(myA.m2) 
<class '__main__.ResettableDict'> # works! 
>>> myA.m1 = 'string!'
>>> type(myA.m2) 
<class 'str'> # no longer a ResettableString! DOH!!!
```

Python has the capability to "overload" most operators. But you can't write a class that generally overloads the `=` (assignment) operator. What to do?

ANSWER: as I said at the beginning, descriptors! We're going to make a descriptor called `Resettable`. A `Resettable` will have a `reset()` method that reverts the value of the member to the default value.

You'll use it like this:

```
class A(object):
    m1 = Resettable('m1', None)
    m2 = Resettable('m2', {})
```

Here is `Resettable`:

```
class Resettable(object):
    '''A class descriptor that can be reset to its default value.'''
    def __init__(self, name, default):
        self.default = default
    def reset(self):
        setattr(self.current_instance, self.name, self.default)
        del self.current_instance
    def __get__(self, obj, typ):
        try:
            return getattr(obj, '_%s' % self.name)
        except AttributeError:
            setattr(obj, self.name, self.default)
            return self.default
        finally:
            self.current_instance = obj
    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        setattr(obj, '_%s' % self.name, value)
```

A Python descriptor provides a lot of functionality. One of those things is "overloading" of both the `=` (assignment) operator (via the `__set__` method; providing this method is optoinal), and the `.` ("get") operator (via the `__get__` method).

Now when you assign a value to your object members, the default Python get and set behavior is overridden by the behavior provided by the descriptor object.

```
>>> myA = A()
>>> myA.m2[1] = 2 
>>> type(A.m2) 
<class '__main__.Resettable'> # works! 
>>> myA.m1 = 'string!'
>>> type(A.m1) 
<class '__main__.Resettable'> # works!!!!! 
>>> myA.m2.reset()
>>> myA.m1.reset()
```

Comment: Thanks Rick for pointing out this page. But m1/m2 is intended for the instance myA not class A. Can you go into a bit regarding implementation in detail?

Comment: @Lazysheep.wang It's true that a descriptor is to be a class `A` object member and not an instance `myA` object member. However, the [descriptor protocol](http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/dunderdsc/) means that when an instance member lookup is initiated, a class-level member descriptor is returned if it exists.

Comment: Thanks Rick. It is a great solution. Actually I defined at least 10 members in this A class, and might keep adding more. I will try to incorporate your solution into my code tomorrow, and update this thread correspondingly. Thanks a lot for your solution in such detail!

Comment: @Lazysheep.wang FYI this isn't working at the moment - need to retool.

Comment: @Lazysheep.wang I'm abandoning this idea. Maybe it could be made to work, but I'm unsure how. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

m1 and m2 are members of the class not instances of it.The members of the class cant call on functions of their containing class, the members can only call functions inside their instance. In sinpler context m1 shouldnt be calling myA.reset() .I'm pretty sure you can just call myA.m1.clear(). If you want reset to do it you could have an argument passed in telling the class which variable to clear.

Comment: I think it is exactly what I want to do - "you could have an argument passed in telling the class which variable to clear." Can you suggest how to implement this method? I want to compare member name, and do different reset operation.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't as elegant as I was hoping for with a descriptor-based solution (which I have abandoned in my other answer), but I think this is how I would to it.

```
class Resettable(object):
    '''A class with "resettable" fields.'''
    _resettables = {}
    def __init__(self):
        for field, value in self._resettables.items():
            setattr(self, field, value)
    def reset(self, field):
        try:
            setattr(self, field, self._resettables[field])
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError('%s is not a resettable field' % field)

class A(Resettable):
    _resettables= dict(m1 = None, m2 = {})
```

Test:

```
>>> myA.m1 = 'string'
>>> myA.reset('m1')
>>> assert myA.m1 is None
```

Instead of doing the heavy lifting in the `reset` method, you could use a different approach entirely and return any values of fields with default values using the `__getattr__` method.

```
class Resettable(object):
    '''A class with "resettable" fields.'''
    _resettables= {}
    def __init__(self):
        for field, value in self._resettables.items():
            setattr(self, field, value)
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        try:
            return self._resettables[attr]
        except KeyError:
            pass
    def reset(self, field):
        if field not in self._resettables:
            raise AttributeError('%s is not a resettable field' % field)
        else:
            try:
                delattr(self, field)
            except AttributeError:
                pass

class A(Resettable):
    _resettables= dict(m1 = None, m2 = {})
```